# Does AirBaltic require you to print boarding pass before arriving at airport to avoid extra costs?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, airbaltic

**With [AirBaltic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirBaltic), after online check-in, can you print the boarding pass at the airport (at a kiosk)?** Or ar they one of those ripoff airlines that make you pay extra if you have *not* printed the PDF beforehand by yourself?

I'm asking because it sounds like the latter, from what they tell me after online check-in:

> **A printed boarding pass is essential to proceed through the security
>   check at the airport.** If you have baggage to check in please remember
>   that the baggage drop-off desk closes at the same time as airport
>   check-in! Please note that there is a checked baggage fee in place.
>
> [...]
>
> Open the boarding pass in PDF format

I'm interested in how this is with AirBaltic in general, or if it varies by airport, in Helsinki, Riga, and Warsaw airports in particular.

Comment: (Accidentally created [`air-baltic`] tag with hyphen, though it should be [`airbaltic`]. Can someone rename it, because [I can't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NC30q.png)?)

Comment: I didn't even know such `rip-off airlines` existed. Can you name a few?

Comment: Ryanair, at least when I last used it some years ago. Probably some other low-cost carriers.

Comment: @Jonik RyanAir lost a court case in Spain over this, my understanding is that they were told in no uncertain terms it's the airline's responsibility to provide a passenger with a ticket.  I assume this would then apply to the whole EU as a ruling, but haven't flown in Europe since I heard this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found some answers at their website at [How to check in for a flight?](https://www.airbaltic.com/en/how-to-check-in):

They **only have self-service kiosks in Riga**:

> Currently available to our passengers travelling from Riga airport,
>   self-check-in kiosks allow you to check in at the airport free of
>   charge.

Also, they do have a **10 EUR airport check-in fee**, but that [does not apply to](https://www.airbaltic.com/en/airport-check-in-fee) "passengers who have already checked in online, via mobile check-in or at a self service check-in kiosk".

They [confirmed on Twitter](https://twitter.com/airBaltic/status/530265072632098816) that they'll print it for free as long as you have checked in online:

> Hello! We’re sorry for late response. **If you've checked in online, you
>   can get a boarding pass at the check-in desk free of charge.**

Anyway, it looks like their **[mobile check-in](https://www.airbalticmobi.com/app/ck.fly?p=mob)** is a better option if you happen to be in possession of a mobile phone, as you avoid queuing at the check-in desk:

> A: With airBaltic mobile check-in you will save time and money, escape
>   queues and the EUR 10 check-in fee at the airport. It gives you
>   flexibility and the possibility to check in on your way to the
>   airport. Please pay attention to the check-in deadline.

You enter booking ref and surname (whether or not you've already done online check-in) and get a "**mobile boarding pass**" with QR code to show at  the gate:

[image]

Edit: Last weekend I used the mobile boarding pass on four separate airBaltic flights, so I can confirm that there is **no need to print anything** by yourself.

Comment: Are there limitations with regards to device compatibility for the mobile boarding pass?

Comment: The mobile site (http://airbalticmobi.com/) *looks like* it works even on some crappier devices ("dumb phones" with simple web browser). If in doubt, just try it with your device when online checkin becomes possible about two days before the flight. In case it doesn't work, do online checkin on a computer and get the boarding pass at airport check-in desk (or print it yourself).

Comment: Ok thanks. I imagine they use a QR-code reader to scan the mobile boarding pass. That's where I imagine incompatibility-related problems could arise.

Comment: Ah, good point. They indeed use a QR reader (so forget my previous comment). From [airBaltic mobile check-in FAQs](https://www.airbaltic.com/en/how-to-check-in): "Any mobile phone with an enabled internet connection (3G/4G/Wi-Fi) can be used to check in online. **The device should be able to display a full size mobile boarding pass (QR code).**"